# Can ToList() change the order of items in a List?

Tags: c#, list

Could the order of items in `list1` and `list2` be different when
`list2 = list1.ToList()` and both are of type `List`?

Comment: That depends on what `list1` is, is it also a `List<T>` or could it be an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `list1` is consistent in its ordering, then `list2` will be in the same order.

It's possible that `list1` is some type that doesn't itself promise to have the same order every time it is enumerated, in which case of course the two might differ, but it is the enumeration logic of `list1` that is responsible for that, not `ToList()`. (The name of `list1` suggests that it is itself a list, in which case the orders would certainly be the same).

One answer here already includes the source of one of the implementations of `ToList()`. It is not the only version of `ToList()` that exists, and corefx optimises for many more cases than netfx does, but it remains that all versions produce the list in the same order as they source would deliver them on enumeration.

Another answer says that this is not guaranteed in the documentation, only by the description of the overload of the `List<T>` constructor that takes an enumeration (which is not, incidentally the only constructor used by all implementations of `ToList()` in all cases).

However, a change to `ToList()` that did not promise to maintain the order would not be accepted.

Consider the case of `someSource.OrderBy(x => x.ID).ToList()`. In such a case (which incidentally, is a case that is optimised in corefx) if `ToList()` could change the order it would obviously remove the point of the `OrderBy()`.

Okay, so what if someone changed `ToList()` in a way that didn't promise to maintain order, but treated `OrderBy()` as a special case? (After all, it's already a special case for performance reasons in one version). Well, that would still break say `someSource.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList()`. In all, if we had a version of `ToList()` that didn't maintain order we'd be able to come up with some sort of linq query where a given order was promised by another part of the query and such an implementation of `ToList()` broke the promise of the query as a whole.

So, barring special-casing a source that explicitly doesn't promise to maintain order (`ParallelEnumerable` doesn't unless you use `AsOrdered()`, since there are a lot of advantages of not maintaining an order unless really necessary when it comes to parallel processing) we can't make a change to `ToList()` that doesn't maintain order without breaking the promises of linq queries as a whole.

So while the guarantee isn't called out in the documentation of `ToList()`, it is nevertheless guaranteed and will not be changed in a later version.

Comment: The source of `ToList()` is just `IEnumerable` and you cannot know "where it comes from", so I suppose one cannot treat `OrderBy` special or different.

Comment: @Gerard you can, and `ToList()` does, know if it looks. At https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs#L30 the `IIListProvider<TSource>` interface looked for is implemented by the results of many linq methods and provide optimised `ToList()` implementations. The result of `OrderBy()` is an example of this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e8f960452234b7c2c0fbcd8b636aa2ad55fa676e/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L52-L67 Note how it avoids allocations and many virtual method calls.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is **No**, order is not gauranteed to be preserved even if both lists are type of `List`.

Because `List` is not a sealed class. Another class could derive from it and override `GetEnumerable` and possibly return items out of order.

Sounds strange, yes. But its possible. So you cant say ToList will return exact same list unless they are both concrete type of `List` and not of any derived type.

The other answer says that its implementation detail that could change in future. I dont think so. List is very essential part of .net collections. Such a unreasanable  breaking change is very unlikey.

Dont worry, as long as you use concrete `List` order is **always** preserved.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, `ToList` will just loop over the source enumerable and keep the same order. `List<T>` guarantees order, so calling `ToList` on it won't change it.

The more nuanced answer however is that you may not be starting with a `List<T>` and may have an more general `IEnumerable<T>` which does not guarantee order at all This means that multiple calls to `source.ToList()` *may* produce different outputs.

In practice however, virtually all implementations of `IEnumerable` will preserve order.

Answer (score 1):

For starters: it's safe to say everybody *expects* that. But why?

According to the documentation, the constructor of `List<T>` that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` is guaranteeing the order is preserved:

> The elements are copied onto the List in the same order they are read by the enumerator of the collection.

While the documentation of `.ToList()` makes no such promises (doesn't say anything to the contrary either though).

Internally, one uses the other, so you are safe, but you are not guaranteed to be safe should the internal implementation of `.ToList()` change. So if you want to be sure, you should call `new List(oldList);` directly.

Smallprint: if you are nit picky about it... I could not find a guarantee that the `IEnumerable<T>` interface would return the elements of a list *in order* either. So both ways, you have to look at what *is*, and if you need to rely on it, maybe write some unit tests asserting this behavior so you get notified immediately should the current behavior change.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no different. Check the source code out.

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

And the part when it creates a list

```
    // Constructs a List, copying the contents of the given collection. The
    // size and capacity of the new list will both be equal to the size of the
    // given collection.
    // 
    public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        if (collection==null)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
        if( c != null) {
            int count = c.Count;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                _items = _emptyArray;
            }
            else {
                _items = new T[count];
                c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
                _size = count;
            }
        }    
        else {                
            _size = 0;
            _items = _emptyArray;
            // This enumerable could be empty.  Let Add allocate a new array, if needed.
            // Note it will also go to _defaultCapacity first, not 1, then 2, etc.

            using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
                while(en.MoveNext()) {
                    Add(en.Current);                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs